# three candidates nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Three candidates, Hillary, Ted, and Jeb decide whether to run for president of 2016. Becoming a president has value 10 to each of the candidates. Running a campaign has cost 4 to candidate. If more than one candidate declares her campaign, each of the candidates is equally likely to win the election.
(a) Write down the game in matrix form
(b) Find all pure-strategy Nash equilibria of the game
There are an infinite number of mixed-strategy Nash equilibria in this game.
(c) Find one symmetric mixed-strategy Nash equilibrium in which each candidate runs with
the same probability.
(d) Find one mixed-strategy Nash equilibrium in which one candidate runs with certainty and
the other two randomize

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This is a question-and-answer site. Please ask a question rather than telling us what to do in the imperative mood.